# How do I fix electron certificate problem?

Tags: javascript, electron, ssl-certificate, desktop-application, client-certificates

when i tried to make a simple hello world app with electron on Windows i get the following error in terminal:

`[15352:0706/053417.545:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 [15352:0706/053417.588:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 [15352:0706/053417.619:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 [15352:0706/053417.661:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 [15352:0706/053418.494:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 [15352:0706/053418.494:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101 [15352:0706/053418.572:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101` 
and it keeps coming
how should i fix it?

i tried adding

```
    app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');
```

but didn't work